# How to code writing type python script

Tags: python, timer

Im doing a menu based program and i want it so when you open the script it will say.
"Loading Menu please wait.."
Then the menu will start appearing but not right away it will start appearing one word at a time as if i am writing it out there and then if you get me.
I have it like this so far for example:

```
    #Imports time so i can delay things:D
import time

# This will ask the end user to input his/her choice ;D
def area():
    print("Loading Menu please wait..")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("  _______________")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("||               ||")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("||Area Calculator||")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("||     V1.0      ||")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("||  By William F ||")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("||_______________||")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Please Select A Shape")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("1. Square")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("2. Rectangle")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("3. Circle")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("4. Triangle")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("5. Exit")
    print()
    time.sleep(1)
    return

#This will call the function to display the menu
area()
```

This works but i want it to be typing itself out as it loads so i tried adding this:

```
print ("  _", time.sleep(1),"______________")
```

Was going to add that after each letter thing but when i tested on one it displayed "None" where the time sleep is?
Any ideas?
Thank you so much. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that can help you out:

```
import time
import sys


def slowshow(text, delay=0.2):
    for c in text:
        time.sleep(delay)
        sys.stdout.write(c)
    print ""

slowshow("Hello, I am Reut Sharabani!")
```

A more fun version of this would be to make it synchronized so you can procceed with calculations without blocking your program:

```
import time
import sys
import threading

# lock the sys.stdout stream when a thread is printing.
slowshow_lock = threading.Lock()

def slowshow(text, delay=0.2):
    slowshow_lock.acquire()
    for c in text:
        time.sleep(delay)
        sys.stdout.write(c)
    print ""
    slowshow_lock.release()

# they will show when needed
threading.Thread(target=slowshow, args=("Hello, I am Reut Sharabani!", )).start()
threading.Thread(target=slowshow, args=("Hello, I am Albus Dumbledore!",)).start()

# this should show immediately, even though we've sent text to printing!
print "VERY COMPLEX BACKGROUND CALCULATION"
```

Comment: I've added a nicer synchronized version if you intend to have time-consuming operations and don't want to wait for the text to print.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to make it "type itself"; this simply removes a newline:

```
import sys, time
sys.stdout.write(' _')
time.sleep(1)
sys.stdout.write('____________")
```

Output:

```
 _(1 second wait)_____________
```